# Beamer navigation bar content overflowing

Tags: beamer

I am creating a presentation in `LaTex` using the `beamer` document class. I am using the Hannover theme. This produces a navigation bar on the left hand side of each slide.

I have a lot of sections and subsections. These are indicated on the navigation bar. The ***problem*** is that ***these overflow the navigation bar***. Neither do I want to delete any section or subsection nor do I want to make the text in the navigation bar smaller.

But still, I want the navigation bar to show all the "relevant" sections and subsections (along with the previous and next ones). How do I achieve this?

***Edit 1***

Here's an MWE (a screenshot of how the navigation bar looks like when there are too many sections and subsections):
[image: MWE]

As you can see, the navigation bar is overflowing. ***I do not want this to happen***. Instead ***I want the following to happen***:

> Whenever I am presenting a section, only that section (and it's
>   subsections along with the name of the previous and next section only)
>   must be displayed on the navigation bar - nothing else. If I move onto
>   a next  section, only this section (and it's subsections along with the
>   name of the previous and next section only) must be displayed on the
>   navigation bar - nothing else.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Please show us a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @dexteritas Hi, I provided an MWE.